# Video Card memory interface compatability

Tags: memory, graphics-card, motherboard, compatibility

[Incoming noob question] [brace for impact]

I've been building my own PCs for over 10 years now, but I'm not exactly rich and technology keeps shooting up lightyears ahead of whatever build I have. I'm getting ready to buy a new video card, but I need a little reassuring first.

I understand that a **PCIe 2.1 x16 slot** *can* accept a card with a PCIe 3.0 connector so that's not an issue. Without getting into specific models (mobo/vga), my question is: Do motherboards set a limit on

- Max VGA RAM clock
- Max VGA RAM amount
- Max VGA RAM interface (bits)

I could not find any such limitations when researching my current mobo.. I just want to be sure.

Comment: I don't think they do. Those are all internal to the card.

Comment: RAM clock and amount NO.  Internal VGA RAM (bits) is also part of the video card.  The mobo has no idea how many bits the memory bus on the video card has, and it does not care.